# Use Javascript Set as a Mongoose SchemaType?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, set

I want to use Javascript's Set standardized in ES2015 as a SchemaType in Mongoose because of uniqueness. But the Mongoose docs do not support Set explicitly, though it seems like the "Mixed" type is a general "anything goes" type (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

I've tried "Mixed" in my web app based on the MEAN stack Reddit/Hacker News tutorial at [Thinkster.io](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial), but have encountered bugs. I want to store all the users that have clicked on upvote in a Set. But only the first time clicking upvote works. After the first time clicking upvote, if the page is refreshed, the upvote count is reset to 0 and clicking on upvote no longer works. I did some console.logging and found that the first time, the upvoters is correctly set to a new Set(). But refreshing the page or subsequent clicks on upvote resets the set object to the more general [object Object] and thus the add and length of set does not work. Thank you for any help!

Posts.js:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      title: String,
      link: String,
      upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
      comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
      author: String,
      upvoters: Object
    });

    PostSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb, upvoter) {          
      if(this.upvoters == null){
        this.upvoters = new Set();
      }
      this.upvoters.add(upvoter);
      this.markModified('upvoters');
      this.upvotes = this.upvoters.length;
      this.save(cb);
    };
    mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `Object` is not a valid scheme type in mongoose.

Also, `Set` in ES6 is much more like `Array` instead of `Object`.

Try changing the schema type of `upvoters` to `[{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User'}]`

If it does not work either, I think you better initialize `new Set()` to a variable instead of assigning directly to the mongoose model object, something like: (not tested)

```
PostSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb, upvoter) { 
  var upvoters = new Set(this.upvoters);
  upvoters.add(upvoter);
  this.upvoters = Array.from(upvoters);
  this.markModified('upvoters');
  this.save(cb);
};
```

Also, I suggest you to remove the property `upvotes`, since its value should always equals to `upvoters.length`, you could consider using `Schema.virtual` to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks! Your code works, but is it a big performance slowdown to use both a Set and Array and converting back and forth between the 2?

Comment: I have not studied much about the performance, please tell if you have found any good articles. By the way, does `Set#add` work when adding mongoose object or mongoose ObjectId? Are there duplicate values when you trigger `upvote()` with the same `upvoter` again?